# vs code does not print full 2-D list in terminal

Tags: python, list, scipy, visual-studio-code

im trying to print data from a .mat file which contains about 400 rows and 800 columns of data, represented by a 2-D list.

I used scipy.io to load the file, and im trying to print the 2-D list in vs code.

but the result is shortened with "..." to something like

[[55, 23, 12...52, 13, 14]

[28, 26, 12...1, 14, 25]

[28, 13, 12...1, 15, 33]

...

[5, 2, 22...32, 11, 4]

[2, 6, 14...15, 54, 25]

[2, 11, 16...3, 25, 13]]

is there a setting in VS code that allows me to print the entire 400x800 matrix?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: That's `numpy's` `threshold` summarization, controlled in `np.set_printoptions`.

Comment: what is result of `type(thing_i_want_to_print)`?

Comment: thanks! im not using numpy tho so I dont think it's that.